# How to save prediction result from a ML model (SVM, kNN) using sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, knn

I have some label data and I am using the classification ML model (SVM, kNN) to train and test the dataset.

My input features look like:
`(442, 443, 0.608923884514436), (444, 443, 0.6418604651162789)`

The label  looks like:
`0, 1`

Then I used `sklearn` to train and test (after splitting the dataset 80% for train and 20% for the test). Code sample is given below:

```
classifiers = [
    SVC(),
    KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
trainingData    = X_train
trainingScores  = y_train
for item in classifiers:
    print(item)
    clf = item
    clf.fit(trainingData, trainingScores)
    
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    print("Accuracy Scor:")
    print(accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
    print("Confusion Matrix:")
    print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test))
    print("Classification Report:")
    print(classification_report(y_pred, y_test))
```

The SVC Accuracy Scor: 0.6639580602883355

The kNN Accuracy Scor: 0.7171690694626475

I can guess that the model is predicting some data correctly. My questions are

1. How can I save the prediction data including the label given by the model in a CSV file.
2. Is it possible to use the `cross-validation` concept here? For example, if I want to apply 5 cross-validations. Then, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
labels_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred ,columns=["predicted_label"])
labels_df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv',index = False)
```

for second question check [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

new_data = pd.concat([X_test,y_pred], axis=1)
new_data.to_csv("Predicted.csv")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).